# building a multidimensional array from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to form a specific multidimensional array from a mysql result set.

I would like it to look like this:

```
array(
'product_name' => 'prod_1',
'categories' => array(1,2,3,4)
);
```

The db result return an array that looks something like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [product_name] => prod_1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [product_name] => prod_1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [product_name] => prod_1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [product_name] => prod_1
    )
```

As you can see, i would like to group the product name and place the id into another array

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: actually where is the category from?  do you want all the id in one array and all the product name in another?

Comment: My query: `SELECT id, product_name FROM parts` Pretty straight forward, i would like the first dimension to contain the grouped product_name and the second to contain all the ID's associated with it

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourarray = array(array('id'=>1, 'product_name' => 'prod_1'), array('id'=>2, 'product_name' => 'prod_2'),array('id'=>3, 'product_name' => 'prod_3'));
$multiarray = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($yourarray);$i++){
    $multiarray['product_name'][] = $yourarray[$i]['product_name'];
    $multiarray['product_id'][] = $yourarray[$i]['id'];
}

print_r($yourarray); //original array
print_r($multiarray); //gives you multi array
```

Something similar to this?

Your original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_name] => prod_1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product_name] => prod_2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [product_name] => prod_3
        )

)
```

The result would print:

```
Array
(
    [product_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => prod_1
            [1] => prod_2
            [2] => prod_3
        )

    [product_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try GROUP_CONCAT. It's something like:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS friends FROM friendships GROUP BY name;
```

Have a look for details here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,287931,287936#msg-287936

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourarray = array(array('id'=>1, 'product_name' => 'prod_1'), array('id'=>2, 'product_name' => 'prod_1'), array('id'=>3, 'product_name' => 'prod_1'),array('id'=>4, 'product_name' => 'prod_1'));

$multiarray = array();
foreach ($yourarray as $value) {
    if(!isset($multiarray['product_name'])) {
        $multiarray['product_name'] = $value['product_name'];
    }    
    $multiarray['categories'][] = $value['id'];
}
print_r($multiarray);
```

Comment: This is fairly close but is outputting all category id's for 1 product instead of only id's related to that product

Comment: your array has just 1 product named prod_1, can you add prod_2,prod_3,... and write the desired array you need?