# mysql table data to multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

hi all i am new to PHP and multidimensional array are complicated for me  .

i have a table

ordered_products(op_id int(), dp_name varchar(), product_id int(), product_quantity int())
and have data like

```
 op_id   dp_name    product_id    product_quantity 

  1      smith        2              3
  2      smith        1              4
  3      adam         3              2
  4      adam         5              6
  5      smith        3              2
```

i need to display which customer purchased which item in how much quantity, i think i need multidimensional array to do this because simple select query is not working

please help

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL join results into an object in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156109/sql-join-results-into-an-object-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Why do you say that a simple select is not working? The data on your table seems to answer your question: `which customer purchased which item in how much quantity`.

Comment: @MostyMostacho i think he meant squashing it down to a multi-dimensional array (JSON-like structure) instead of having a 2D array of possibly repeating values.

Comment: i just want to is ..that i have a customer logged in and i have a page of shopping history to the customer his shipping history from the above table .. .i am confused what do to ... simple select or mulldimen array ??

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [building a multidimensional array from mysql with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346567/building-a-multidimensional-array-from-mysql-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter whether you use a multidimensional array or just use the result set as-is. It depends on how you use the data after. You need to use the standard result set to create the multidimensional array anyway, so it's up to you if you wish to use the result set as-is to show the customer's history or first create the multidimensional array and then use that.